# Can an Azure Serverless Function handle custom SAML header content?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an existing WCF client app calling a SOAP service that has custom SAML header bits. The WCF client has extended the SAML classes to handle some very specific customizations - how can I accomplish this in Azure serverless Functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware to handle custom authorization in azure functions. Header is accessible inside the middleware! Just extend `IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware`
and register your middleware!